# How to click a button through a shortcut with javascript without causing a page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, keyboard-shortcuts, page-refresh

I need some shortcuts in my web application, that will do the same as when a user clicks on a button, or presses the button with the accesskey.

I simplified my code to show you my problem:

```
<html>
<head><script src="jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>
<form>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">text</div>
        <input name="cmdChangeText" type="submit" value="change text" onclick="document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText='text is changed'; return false;" />

        <input name="cmdTestButton" type="submit" value="hello" onclick="alert('hello'); return false;" accesskey='z' />
    </body>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = function() {
        if (event.keyCode == 83) { //83 = 's'
            window.$('[accesskey=z]').click();
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

The first button changes the text.
When you click the second button, or click it through accesskey (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> in IE), you get the alert, but the page does not reload: the text is still changed!

When I press some button, the <kbd>S</kbd> in this example, I do get the alert, but the page gets reloaded! Why is the `return false;` ignored this way, and what can I do about it?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, using IE8 and Chrome. What browser you're using?

Comment: Are you sure? First change the text, and than press 's', the text should not change again. I tested the code in IE8. Don't forget the jquery file!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either. The return false seems to be doing its job.

Comment: onclick="alert('hello'); return false" - you missed ';' after "return false" at the end

Comment: I did forget the ';' after the return false, but the problem stays. The solutions of Art and baked below work both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get rid of the `onclick="alert('hello'); return false"` stuff and attach events using jQuery.

After that, you can try cancel the event bubbling:

```js
$('#myInput2').click(
    function() {
        alert('hello')
        return false
    }
 )
```

Just a hunch.

Comment: Thanks for this. Your solution and the solution of baked both work. I have a button in ASP.NET and in the 'OnClientClick' a lot of javascript happens, so i need to change that code to jquery events like you show here. No more 'return false' in button clicks for me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons different names, in this example I have used 'test1' and 'test2' and add the following code.

```
$('input[name=test1]').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myDiv').innerText('text is changed');
});

$('input[name=test2]').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
});
```

An input of type 'submit' will submit the page by default. Using 'preventDefault()' method on the event will, unsurprisingly prevent the default action. If you **want** the page to reload just remove this line.